# iptables Port Forwarding not working

Tags: linux, iptables, firewall

I'm facing the problem, that my iptables rules aren't working anymore after I changed OS from Ubuntu 8.04 to Debian Squeeze.

I'm trying to do a Port Forwarding by

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $extip -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5777 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.169:5777

/proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forwarding is set

All policies are set to ACCEPT

192.168.10.169 is in FORWARD chain
```

tcpdump output:

```
IP some_ip.33517 > ext_ip.5777: Flags [S], seq 3521672809, win 14600, options [mss 1450,sackOK,TS val 1691129923 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
IP ext_ip.5777 > some_ip.33517: Flags [R.], seq 0, ack 3521672810, win 0, length 0
```

As you can see, there is a RST sent after SYN.
I have no clue why this is happening.

I hope someone can help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does your `nat` table currently look like? And, is the service you intend to connect to actually running?

Comment: Just the PREOTUING line and iptables `-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.10.169 -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source ext_ip` Yes, the service is running. I can connect from the firewall box

Comment: Which interface did you do your tcpdump on?  In the case of NAT you might need to do something like `tcpdump -qni any port 5777`.

Comment: Yep, I did tcpdump -i any

Comment: Is eth0 actually the "outside" interface?

Comment: Yes eth0 is Internet, eth1 is LAN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally solved the problem myself. After hours of trying almost everything, it was the interface parameter.

so this worked on the old machine

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $extip -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5777 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.169:5777
```

but on the new machine it works only without -i eth0, even though the interface have the same names

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d $extip -p tcp -m tcp --dport 5777 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.10.169:5777
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.